# Bounding growth of generalised mean $M_p(a)$ as $p$ increases

Tags: inequality, means, holder-inequality

This is a follow-up question to the one [previously asked here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632426/relationship-between-generalized-mean-ratios-m-4a-m-2a-vs-m-2a-m-1a) on the geometric growth rate of generalized mean. For some $p$ and positive numbers $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, let $M_p(a)$ denote the [generalised or Hölder mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), defined as
\begin{align}
M_p(a) = \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p \right)^{1/p}, && a_1,\dots,a_n\ge 0, p\in\mathbb{R}^+
\end{align}
It well-known property of generalised means that for any given $a$, the value of $M_p(a)$ increases monotonically in $p$, and strictly so if $a_i$'s are not all equal. The following question attempts to quantify the growth when they are not necessarily equal:

> Question: For some fixed $a$, consider the sequence $m_k := M_{2^k}(a)$ corresponding to generalised means with power series $p=1,2,4,\dots$. Is there some constant $c_n$ such that
> $$ c_n \left(\frac{m_{k+2}}{m_{k+1}}\right)^2\le \frac{m_{k+1}}{m_k}$$
> where $0 < c_n < 1$ crucially does not depend on $a$.

**Possible approach**
Observations:

- If the bound holds universally for $c_n$ and $k=0$, the rest of the inequalities are automatically implied by the base case on the scaled vector $a_i\mapsto 2^k a_i$.

Define $f(x) = \log M_{1/x}(a)$ we can restate the inequality in terms of $f$:
\begin{align}
\log c_n + 2 (f(1/4)-f(1/2)) \le f(1/2) - f(1) 
\end{align}
We can also state this result in terms of slope:
\begin{align}
1/2\log(c_n) +\rho(1/4,1/2) \le \rho(1/2,1), && \rho(a,b):=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}
\end{align}
Since $f(x)$ is convex (as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632426/relationship-between-generalized-mean-ratios-m-4a-m-2a-vs-m-2a-m-1a)), a sufficient condition can be obtained by using derivatives:
$$
f'(1)-f'(1/4) \le O(1) 
$$
which can be resulted from a bound on second derivative
$$
 f''(x) = O(1)\qquad x\in[1/4,1]
$$
From the second derivative derivation,
$$
 f''(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}\left[ \frac{\sum a_i^{1/x} (\log(a_i))^2}{\sum a_i^{1/x}} - \left(\frac{\sum a_i^{1/x} \log(a_i)}{\sum a_i^{1/x}} \right)^2 \right]
$$
This can be re-arranged to
$$
f''(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}\left[\frac{\sum_{i,j\le n} a_i^{1/x}a_j^{1/x} (\log(a_i/a_j))^2}{\sum_{i,j\le n} a_i^{1/x}a_j^{1/x}}\right]
$$
we can think of the latter formula for $f''(x)$ as weighted average of $\log(a_i/a_j)^2$ terms with weights $a_i^{1/x} a_j^{1/x}$, which allows us to conclude it's not greater than log of maximum ratio between $a_i$'s:
$$
f''(x)\le \max_{i,j}\log(a_i/a_j)^2
$$
However, this introduces a dependency on $a$, and hence is a weaker result, most likely because bounding average with min is a crude approximation.

**Possible value $c_n$**

As it is common with inequalities involving means, it is best to check the all-equal and all-except-one-zero cases:

1. If $a_1=\dots=a_n$, both sides being $1$ and inequality holds trivially with $c_n=1$
2. If only one value is non-zero $a_1>0,a_2=\dots=a_n=0,$ we have $M_4(a)/M_2(a) = n^{1/4},$ and $M_2(a)/M_1(a)=n^{1/2}$, and the inequality again holds with $c_n=1$.

At this point, I took a guess that $c_n=1$ will uniformly hold for all possible $a_i$'s. Thanks to the comment by @Vincenzo in the original post, this turned out to be false. Based on this counter-example, I'll try to investigate the ratios with a special case of a geometric sequence for $a_i$'s.

Consider $a_i=\alpha^{i-1}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and some $\alpha\in (0,1]$ to be determined later. Since the ratios are scale-invariant, starting with $a_1=1$ suffices. Note that $\alpha=1$ corresponds to the all-equal case, and $\alpha\to 0^+$ converges to the all-but-one-zero case. Thus, it is interesting if the optimal $\alpha$ (one leading to smallest $c_n$) is in between the two extremes.

We have
\begin{align}
M_p(a) = \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i^p\right)^{1/n} 
= \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\alpha^p)^n\right)^{1/p} 
= (n)^{-1/p}\left(\frac{1-\alpha^{np}}{1-\alpha^p}\right)^{1/p}
\end{align}
We can conclude:
\begin{align}
\frac{M_{2p}(a)}{M_p(a)}=n^{1/2p} \left(\frac{1+\alpha^{pn}}{1+\alpha^{p}}\right)^{1/2p}
\implies c_n=\frac{M_2(a)}{M_1(a)}\left(\frac{M_4(a)}{M_2(a)}\right)^{-2}=\left(\frac{(1+\alpha^{2n})^2(1+\alpha)}{(1+\alpha^{n})(1+\alpha^2)^2}\right)^{1/4}
\end{align}
If $n$ is sufficiently large and $\alpha<1$, by approximating $1+\alpha^{2n}$ and $1+\alpha^n$ by $1$, $c_n$ can be approximated by
\begin{align}\tag{*}
c_n&\approx \left(\frac{1+\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)^2}\right)^{1/4},
\end{align}
Finally, we can lower-bound the RHS by finding the arg-min $\alpha$, which turns out to be $\alpha=2/3$, and the corresponding minimum value is $RHS(*)\ge 0.94539...$ Because this value is not close to $1$, this suggests a somewhat surprising inequality
\begin{align}
\min_{\alpha\in(0,1)} \left(\frac{1+\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)^2}\right)^{1/4} = 0.9453... \text{ for $\alpha=2/3$} \implies \min_{0<\alpha<1} c_n = 0.9453... - o(n)
\end{align}
where $o(n)$ presumably goes down exponentially in $n$ (using negative sign $-o(n)$ to emphasis that it's possibly slightly lower for finite $n$)

Clearly, all these were drawn for a very special case of a a geometric series. But th fact that an "optimal" $\alpha$ exists for a geometric sequence, suggests that anything significantly slower than or faster than exponential dependency of $a_i$ on $i$, eg. $a_i = i\alpha + \beta $ or $a_i= \alpha^{i^2} $, is unlikely to lead to a lower $c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly for any positive random variable $X$we have  $E(X^2)\leq E(X)^{2/3}E(X^4)^{1/3}$ by Holder inequality, so your attempts with $c_n=1$ are futile.

Comment: Yes, that was indeed $c_n=1$ was the erroneous guess in the earlier post, but the main question here is for $c_n = .94$ or some constant slightly smaller than $1$.